# WiFi does not connect anymore after libgcrypt

Tags: networking, wireless, security, spotify, libgcrypt

I am a total beginner in Ubuntu. 
I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and everything was working fine, until I tried to install Spotify. This required the installation of libgcrypt11, which was succesfull. 
However after reebooting the computer the wifi stopped working: I could still see the networks, but not connect to them anymore. The connection would time out withoug giving me any notice.

Is there anybody who experienced some related problems? 
Is there a fix for this?

The output of the wifi diagnostic is posted in te link below.

Thank you!

Ciro 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12757067/

Comment: Line 4 says `Hardware error detected.` Maybe not always, but this could be the reason.